# How to arrange items in multiple row when it's overloaded in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row

I want it to look like this
[image]

when display the category with multiple rows. Instead overloaded the item go to the next row  but it looks like this
[image]

### The code

```
                    /* Category */
                    Container(
                        width: 250,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                for ( var i = 0; i < locationTypes.length; i++)
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 6, vertical: 5),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 6, vertical: 5),

                                    // to make corner rounded
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                          typeBackgroundColor[numbers[i]],
                                          typeBackgroundColor[numbers[i] * 2],
                                        ]),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                          color: typeBorderColor[numbers[i]],
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(20))
                                    ),
                                    // End of corner rounded

                                    child: TextButton(
                                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                          minimumSize: Size(50, 30),
                                          tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize
                                              .shrinkWrap,
                                          alignment: Alignment.center),
                                      child: Text(
                                        locationTypes[i],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: typeTextColor[numbers[i]],
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        //save type
                                        locationType = locationTypes[i];

                                        //change style
                                        //1A) reverse the colors
                                        int num = numbers[i];

                                        //2) remove from all
                                        setState(() {
                                          for (int j = 0; j <
                                              numbers.length; j++) {
                                            if (numbers[j] == 1) {
                                              numbers[j] = 0;
                                            }
                                          }
                                        });

                                        //1B) reverse the colors
                                        if (num == 0)
                                          setState(() {
                                            numbers[i] = 1;
                                          });
                                        bool flag = false;
                                        for (int j = 0; j <
                                            numbers.length; j++) {
                                          if (numbers[j] == 1) {
                                            flag = true;
                                          }
                                        }
                                        setState(() {
                                          isButtonActive[17] = flag;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    ),
                    /*end of Category*/
```

Thank you for reading till the end, it really means a lot to me <3
I'm sorry if this is having been posted. I tried to look for someone like me, but I didn't find. Maybe they use a different word to express the problem.

Comment: Use Wrap instead of Row, it will align overflowed items to next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `Wrap()` Widget  instead of `Row()` which will help you to achieve your expected UI

```dart
Wrap(
  children:
      List.generate(widget.feedPostModel!.sizeIds!.length, (index) {
    return CustomText(
      title: (widget.feedPostModel!.sizeIdsName![index].name)
              .toString() +
          ",",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
  }),
),
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some code-snippet

Comment: You are welcome and Keep Fluttering <3

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for this in the past two hours